# Can I overload the + operator in Toit?

Tags: toit

I'm writing code in Toit. I would like to have the `+` operator do something meaningful when applied to one of my classes, `Vector`, that represent two-dimensional vectors.

My code looks like this:

```
class Vector:
  x/float ::= ?
  y/float ::= ?
  constructor .x .y:
```

Can I somehow support this code?

```
main:
  v1 := Vector 1.0 2.0
  v2 := Vector 3.0 4.0
  log v1 + v2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `+` to your `Vector` class as a user-defined operator. The solution looks like this:

```
class Vector:
  x/float ::= ?
  y/float ::= ?
  constructor .x .y:
  operator + other/Vector -> Vector: 
    return Vector (x + other.x) (y + other.y)
```

The `other/Vector` part is syntax for defining that the `+` operator on `Vector` takes a single argument of type `Vector`. The `-> Vector` part is syntax for declaring that it returns something of type `Vector`.

Some prefer to refer to this as 'operator overriding' not 'operator overloading', because it doesn't fully allow you to have multiple different implementations for different argument types.