# How do I overload multiplication to the left in toit?

Tags: toit

In the question [Can I overload the + operator in Toit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63322805/can-i-overload-the-operator-in-toit) it shows how to overload right-addition by another vector. If I have a vector class for example, how do I overload scalar multiplication to the left? In the code below, I would like z and y to evaluate to the same, but I (understandably) get the error `Lookup failed when calling "multiply_from_float_" on a Vec1f.`

```
class Vec1f:
  x/float ::= ?

  constructor x_in/Number:
    x = x_in.to_float

  operator * factor/Number -> Vec1f:
    return Vec1f
      x * factor

main:
  x := Vec1f 1.0

  y := x * 2.0
  // error here
  z := 2.0 * x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no clean way to implement this feature.

That said, if you are willing to rely on internal implementation details, here is, how you would do it:

Binary operations in numbers are implemented as double-dispatch. For example, the `operator *` on a `float` calls `multiply_from_float_` on the given operand.

As such, it's relatively straight-forward to make `Vecif` a working operand:

```
class Vecif:
  ...
  multiply_from_float_ f/float: return this * f
```

Note that this solution is brittle for two reasons:

1. it depends on internal implementation details (like the name `multiply_from_float_`).
2. it is typewise not safe.

For point 2, have a look at the `Number` class's `operator *` declaration:

```
  abstract operator *  other/Number
```

The `Number` class expects `other` to be a number.
Currently, the type of `other` isn't propagated to the overriding methods, but we eventually would like to do that, and then `Vecif` would not be accepted anymore.